# Using Win32 API CreateProcess in FireBreath Framework

Tags: c++, browser-plugin, firebreath

I'm trying to develop a browser plugin using Firebreath framework. The first thing I would like to achieve is to make the plugin able to do traceroute. For now I'm doing it on Windows7. Currently I chose to use Win32API CreateProcess to call the command shell. By setting dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW , I'm able to hide the command shell window during execution.

**PROBLEM :** The createProcess is implemented in a method called run() where I called it using JS for testing. When I called plugin().run(), the traceroute is working well, and the output was succesfully written in a textfile as I wanted. However during the execution, the browser become unresponsive and lastly the plugin crashed seconds after the traceroute completed. As I am new to plugin development and only have a little knowledge on c++ , I wonder why this problem arisen. FYI, if I did not hide the commandshell window, the plugin worked wonder - the browser was responsive while the traceroute was executed.

Answer (score 1):

It is very important in any NPAPI plugin (with FireBreath or otherwise) that you don't block the main (the javascript) thread. What you're trying to do could be done in a couple of ways; I'd probably pass in a callback, start a new thread, do the createprocess there, and then fire the js callback when it completes with the result.

See [FireBreath Tips: Asynchronous Javascript Calls](http://colonelpanic.net/2010/12/firebreath-tips-asynchronous-javascript-calls/).

The one thing to watch out for is you need to be able to terminate the thread (and the process) if the plugin is shut down during the call.